# Why does the following code print out 10 instead of null?

Tags: php, oop

The following code outputs `10`. Why is that?

```
<?php 

class a{
    var $c;

    public function a(){
        $this->c=10;
    }
}

class b extends a{

    public function print_a(){
        print $this->c;
    }
}

$b=new b;
$b->print_a();
```

Comment: what does it output if you change the name of the `function a()` ?

Comment: Renaming it to `function aa()` would make it function properly. @Oliboy50

Comment: Renaming it to anything else (including `b()`) makes the output `null`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `public function a()` is a constructor.

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class.

see more at [PHP constructor manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link. Failed this in an interview today.

Answer (score 3):

In older versions of PHP `public function a` is treated as `class a` constructor. Because there is no constructor in `class b`, `class a` constructor is called and `$c` is set to 10;

Answer (score 2):

Well you actually named your function the samename as the class, this is an implicit constructor. So in short it's the same as `__construct()`.

In OOP you have to keep in mind, that if you extend a class it's parent constructor is implicitly called when you create a new instance unless you explicitly override the constructor.